# libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.28-10 is to be installed

Tags: installation, apt

Everything worked perfectly when I am using Ubuntu.
But when I come to Debian and try install a package, this happens.

What should I do?

```
$ sudo apt install google-drive-ocamlfuse

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-drive-ocamlfuse : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.28-10 is to be installed
```

I also try to download and install libc6 (>= 2.29).

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.29-2_amd64.deb

dpkg: regarding libc6_2.29-2_amd64.deb containing libc6:amd64:
 libc6:amd64 breaks locales (<< 2.29)
  locales (version 2.28-10) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive libc6_2.29-2_amd64.deb (--install):
 installing libc6:amd64 would break locales, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6_2.29-2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: What does your `sources.list` files look like?

Comment: Please append output of `$ apt policy libc6 locales` to your question. You should not start to download and install packages using dpkg, except if you know exactly what you are doing!

Comment: google-drive-ocamlfuse doesn't appear to be a package packaged by Debian. => [DontBreakDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian). You could get the debianized source (deb-src) and rebuilt the package to match your own libraries. Except now you started breaking your debian...